# Firebase Rules check

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

So I am assuming that my firebase rules are insecure :
I need second thoughts on it
below I set rules like:

1. Anyone can read and create(register)
2. Registered users can read messages
3. Registered users can create messages

> ```
> rules_version = '2';
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     match /usernames/{usernames} {
>       allow read;
>       allow create;
>     }
>     match /users/{users} {
>       allow read;
>       allow create;
>     }
>     match /messages/{messages} {
>       allow read;
>       allow create : if request.auth.uid != null;
>     }
>
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Anyone can read and create(register)

```
match /users/{users} {
   allow read, write: if true;
}
```

> 2. Registered users can read messages (and No one can write it)

```
match /users/{users} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow write: if false;
}
```

> 3. Registered users can create messages (and No one can read it)

```
match /messages/{messages} {
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow read: if false;
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is create, update, and delete.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations